# Deploying issue using netlify (during the building process)

Tags: deployment, netlify, hugo

I have built a site using Hugo from a template called uBlogger, pushed everything on GitHub and then I used Netlify to deploy the site.
On the deploy log, it says

```
Error: Error building site: TOCSS: failed to transform "css/db6b6c.scss" (text/x-scss): SCSS processing failed: file "stdin", line 1, col 6: Invalid CSS after "#id-1{": expected "}", was "<nil>}"
```

Honestly I have been trying to look for the file "db6b6c.csss", which doesn't exist in my project, and I haven't found any information online so I have no clue of what to do. Does that mean I have to go through all the files there is in my folder and look for "#id-1{" ?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is similar to [this thread](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-error-tocss-failed-to-transform-style-sass-text-x-sass/13776), where:

- the OP did not initially [download](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases) the extended version of Hugo,
- the OP, on Netlify, one user switched to Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 (default, instead of an older one), and everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The parameters were already set to "Ubuntu Xenial 16.04", so I did not change that. I tried to rename the folder "scss" to "sass" and downloaded the extended version of hugo but the problem persists (it remains the same). Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @VirgileBRIAN No problem, it was worth a shot. I still suspect the extended version of Hugo is relevant this instance, though, from your comment, not enough.